# How do I do a right click on a 'magic mouse'?

Tags: mac, mouse

We’ve just won a brand new iMac. It came with an Apple keyboard, Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad. The keyboard works well, although it's weird not having a numeric keypad. The trackpad also works well.

But while the mouse seems to connect fine and I can scroll and click ok, for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do right-clicking on the mouse?

I did try looking for a Control Panel to try and fix this, but there isn’t one.

Comment: By left-clicking on the buy button [here](http://a.co/4W1yKuy).

Comment: @JasonC Hey! I'm happy with my Magic Mouse!  (I know you're joking, but in all seriousness, the touch surface + BetterTouchTool is super useful and I definitely recommend it to anyone who likes trackpad gestures but also wants to use a mouse (as long as you get the version that takes AAs))

Comment: May want to take look at these to for help transitioning from PC to Mac. Its been a year but still good to know. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204216 https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25102?locale=en_US

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no *Control Panel* like in Windows or the old Classic Mac OS systems of years ago. Instead, what macOS has are System Preferences. You can access this from the Apple Menu and selecting the **System Preferences…** option.

Once you do you’ll see a list of Preferences Panes you can access by using a single mouse click. There are two you can utilise to address your issue, because both the Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad can be set up to do what you’re calling a right-click.

Below are screenshots of both the Mouse and Trackpad preference panes:

[image]

[image]

Note that when you look at both these preference panes you will see options for a Secondary click.  This is the setting that will enable the right-click you’re looking for.

I suggest while you’re in System Preferences you also have a *play* with what else is available.

Finally, you may find the [Mac tips for Windows switchers](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204216) site of great interest to you.

Comment: The problem with the magic-mouse' right-click functionality is that if you're like me and rest your index and middle fingers on the top of the mouse then you have to actively lift your index finger off the left side before you can depress the right-side with your middle finger for a right-click. This got tiring very quickly it's why I returned my Magic Mouse for a refund and got a Logitech mouse with real, actual buttons.

Comment: @Dai You've just solved for me one of the biggest stress points of using a mac for me - the inconsistently working right click!

Comment: honestly I find the magic mouse to be WAY better when used as a one-button mouse. Then both fingers can rest on the mouse surface at all times.

Answer (score 18):

Hold down the <kbd>⌃CTRL</kbd> key and click with the mouse. This will act as a right click.

Or you can set it up thru ** Apple menu** → **System Preferences...** → **Mouse** and check **Secondary Click**.

Answer (score 0):

two finger tap on the pad is equivalent to right click with a mouse

Comment: This answer was already given.  In addition, the user can change what a 2-finger tap on the mouse does so this answer is not only a duplicate but it's incomplete.  Please edit your answer to include new or updated info.  See [answer] for tips on how to give good answers. - From Review